# Вывод сообщения в консоль Windows при некорректном количестве параметров

Tags: java, командная-строка

Есть следующая проблема: не выводится текст в консоль.
Есть некоторое приложение, которое обрабатывает исходный текстовый файл, выводит результат во второй и принимает на вход 4 аргумента:

```
input.txt output.txt -k -u
```

где `k` и `u` - какие-то параметры запуска.
В целом, запуск приложения в консоли выглядит следующим образом:

```
program.exe input.txt output.txt -k -u
```

При правильном количестве параметров программа отрабатывает корректно. Но если, к примеру, количество параметров меньше 4, то программа должна сообщить об этом и завершить свою работу. Программа завершается, но текст в консоль не выводится.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    if (args.length != 4) {
        System.out.println("Invalid format");
        return; 
    }
    ...
}
```

[image: Пример запуска]

Первый запуск отработал как надо. Второй должен был вывести сообщение об ошибке. Почему сообщение не выводится?

Answer (score 5):

Запускайте программу с использованием `java -jar`:

```
java -jar program.jar arg1 arg2 arg3
```

В этом случае в консоли появится:

> Invalid format

Comment: Да, спасибо, так работает нормально, а что делать с exe-шником, который я конвертировал из jar-a? Он также ничего не выводит в консоль.

Comment: @Денис это смотря что делает этот .exe-файл и как вы его собирали. Если он просто запускает .jar-файл, то достаточно и в него упаковать запуск с `java -jar`.

Comment: вот тут не понял, как в него упаковать `java -jar`? (собирал с помощью 
 Launch4j)

Comment: @Денис я, к сожалению, давно не пользовался Launch4j, поэтому не помню что и как там делается.  Насчет "упаковки": представьте себе обычный .bat-файл, в котором присутствует всего одна строка: `java -jar program.jar`. По факту там ещё надо параметры командной строки пробрасывать и т.д., но я про саму идею. А теперь представьте, что у вас .exe-файл делает то же самое что и .bat. Вот про этот случай я и написал. Такой .exe-файл вообще можно собрать самому в Visual Studio. Если же Launch4j полностью интегрирует .jar в .exe (мало ли), то тогда надо смотреть как он это делает.

Answer (score 0):

Все легко. Просто используйте команду полного выхода, который есть в классе System.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
if (args.length != 4) {
    System.out.println("Invalid format");
    System.exit(0); // Та самая команда
}
...
```